# Android list view with static selected position

Tags: android, listview, gallery

I've working on app that need custom list view...

List view should act like some kind of vertical gallery.
In gallery selected item is always on center.

In my app I use navigation keys only or remote controller.
So there is no fling or regular scrolling effect.

I need for example second element in my list to be selected always.
If I want to move up, all elements are scrolled one place up, and selected item has to be changed, but on same place on the screen like previous selected item.

It's the same thing like gallery only vertical.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Is there a vertical gallery implementation?
How can I make gallery widget vertical?
Or how to customize list view to act like that?

Tnx!

Comment: I think you should check Timescape-UI source code of sony xperia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed this using setSelected() method on ListView item...and managing key listener.
Didn't found smarter way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

try setting onClick Listener on ListView

```
ListView listView1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

then implemt a class   class SearchItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener

and set listview.onItemClickListenr you will get position and view.

```
        Hope this helps
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current visible first postion by using,

```
mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

after getting the current visible position and its respective data, you can perform your desired task (i.e. display the large image after getting the thumbnail or something like this).

**OR**

If you don't want to depend on only first or last position and want to select some other visible row then you can do something like this,

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        int visiblePosition = position % nObjects; // nObjects if the total number of objects to display

        if(visiblePosition == yourDesiredPosition){

         // do your custom work here.

        }

    }
```

Here is a demo for [vertical slide show](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo),

Hope this will give you some hint about implementing your functionality.